# Error of context in .aspx when calling c# methods

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, leaflet

In my front end, I'm trying to call methods dynamically, but I keep getting errors of contexts.
My code looks like this and the error is given by my "i":
.aspx :

```
<script src="https://PCYULD0029:8012/Maps/leaflet.js"></script>
<script >
... some code

        AllObject = "<%=(ParseMapObjects())%>";
        L.marker([0, 0], 0).addTo(map).bindPopup("test");
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ObjLongitude = AllObject[i].Longitude;
            ObjLatitue = AllObject[i].Latitude;

            CreateMarkers(ObjLongitude, ObjLatitude)
            L.marker([0, 0], 0).addTo(map).bindPopup("test");
            L.marker([0, 50], 0).addTo(map).bindPopup(ObjLatitue);
        }


        function CreateMarkers(ObjLong, ObjLat) {
            L.marker([ObjLong, ObjLat], 0).addTo(map).bindPopup("Test");
        }

        ... some code
   </script>
```

.aspx.cs :

```
public List<MapObjectEntity> ParseMapObjects()
{
    List<MapObjectEntity> MapObjects = new List<MapObjectEntity>();

   .... Some code

    return MapObjects;

}
public class MapObjectEntity
{
    // Properties
    public Guid MapObjectGuid { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public Guid Link { get; set; }
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
    public int RelativeHeight { get; set; }
    public int RelativeWidth { get; set; }
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public bool ObjectShowFov { get; set; }
    public Guid MapObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

So, in ParseMapObjects, I return a List of MapObjectEntity. I then try to catch that in my .aspx (frontend), so that I can use it as an object (ex: Object.property).

With the line `AllObject = "<%=(ParseMapObjects())%>";` I succeed at pulling the object, but I can't seem to find a way to use `AllObject` to get my properties (ex: AllObject[0].Latitude).

My objective here is to loop through my AllObject and extract all the Latitude and Longitude values. But I can

thank you

Comment: You can not call public method of code behind from client by using this approach. You need to declare method as webmethod and use AJAX to call it.. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless ParseMapObjects() returns a JSON string (something like caner's answer) 
this won't work.

And bear in mind, once the page has loaded, this value will be fixed, since it's the *result* of the C# method that is output to the page, not a reference to the method. If you run the Javascript multiple times, the value assigned to `AllObject` on that line will stay fixed, because it's basically a static object in the JS context (check the View Source of your browser to see what is output).

You can't call a C# method directly from JavaScript, and vice versa. C# executes on the server and constructs the HTML, CSS and JS to output to the browser. JavaScript runs in the client's browser after the page (i.e. the content generated by the C#) has been downloaded from the server to the browser and initialised. They are in totally separate environments (usually on different computers) and intrinsically have no knowledge of each other. This separation is a vital concept to grasp if you want to develop web applications.

If you want communication between the client (browser) and the server outside of the normal page load / refresh / postback mechanism, then you need to use AJAX functionality, or even, if you want real-time communication, something like WebSockets and/or SignalR.

Comment: I had to convert everything to JSON, you were right! Now I'm able to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need serialization...

```
 public string ParseMapObjects()
 {  
        List<MapObjectEntity> MapObjects = new List<MapObjectEntity>();

        return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MapObjects);
    }
```

and access in your script like

```
var AllObject = <%=(ParseMapObjects())%>;
```

Comment: I tried this, but if I check the content of AllObject, I only get this : "[]". I tried to use it to like: AllObject.Longitude   and I'm not getting anything, even the intellisense doesn't show me anything

Comment: Have you filled your list? You should get your return json like this    `<script> $(document).ready(function () { var AllObject = <%=(ParseMapObjects())%>;  }); </script>`

Comment: maybe you have problem in your `some code`.Can you post that?

Comment: and try debuging `ParseMapObjects()`